# Trying to use StateNotifierProvider as per documentation

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

After reading the flutter_riverpod and riverpod documentation for `ConsumerWidget`and `StateNotifierProvider`respectively, I adapted the example code with the following:

This is my StateNotifier class:

```dart
class SelectedFoodsNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Food>> {
  SelectedFoodsNotifier() : super([]);

  void add(Food food) {
    state = [...state, food];
  }

  void remove(int foodId) {
    state = [
      for (final food in state)
        if (food.id != foodId) food,
    ];
  }
}
```

This is my provider:

```dart
final selectedFoodsProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => SelectedFoodsNotifier());
```

And this is my ConsumerWidget class:

```dart
import 'package:diabretes/providers/providers.dart';
import 'package:diabretes/respository/DatabaseRepository.dart';
import 'package:diabretes/widgets/FoodCalculator/no_foods_selected.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

class CalculatorDrawer extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    List<Food> selected_foods = watch(selectedFoodsProvider);

    return AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                offset: Offset(0, 0),
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.20),
                blurRadius: 16,
                spreadRadius: 2)
          ],
        ),
        child: NoFoodsSelected());
  }
}
```

But the line

```dart
List<Food> selected_foods = watch(selectedFoodsProvider);
```

is giving the following error: `The argument type 'StateNotifierProvider<SelectedFoods, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ProviderBase<Object?, List<Food>>'`

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it help if you type your provider like so?

```
final StateNotifierProvider<SelectedFoodsNotifier, List<Food>> selectedFoodsProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => SelectedFoodsNotifier());
```

I make a point of always explicitly typing my providers to avoid typing errors when using my providers.

Answer (score 0):

Try `final selectedFoodsProvider = StateNotifierProvider<SelectedFoodsNotifier, List<Food>>((ref) => SelectedFoodsNotifier());`

`StateNotifierProvider` takes two generic arguments.